# Character comparions java for Unipolar Encoding

Tags: java, comparison, char

The issue here is the conditionals inside the for loop are not being entered for some reason. Namely  `if (samp==1){`Since all characters should be 0 or 1 one of these two should be entered at all times instead neither of them is being entered and I am not sure what is going on. It should be a simple character comparison. Also I have tested it to see that the 'samp'variable is correctly sampling the bit sequence one character at a time.

Could really use some help here. I am sure its mind numbingly simple.

```
//This method will take in a binary bit sequence which should be set up correctly from above
    //Then it should print the Unipolar encoding of the waveform
    public static void Unipolar(String s){
        String code ="";
        char samp='9';
        char[] charArray = s.toCharArray();  //turn the input bit sequence into a char array for simplicity

        String topline="";     //the method I chose was to keep a consistent 3 strings to draw the output
        String midline="";
        String botline="";



        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        samp = charArray[i];
        System.out.println(samp);
            //depending on if the current character is a 1 or a 0 a differnt pattern will be added to the 
            //string to be outputted
            if (samp==1){
                topline+="*****"; 
                midline+="*    ";
                botline+="*    ";
            }
            if (samp==0){
                topline+="     ";
                midline+="     ";
                botline+="*****";
            }
        }
        System.out.println(topline);
        System.out.println(midline);
        System.out.println(botline);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the character values when comparing `chars`:

```
if (samp == '1') {
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks I realized it almost as soon as I posted it, Think I should delete this question or leave it up for others reference?

Comment: It does have merit but it is entirely up to you. :)

Answer (score 0):

OK nevermind.... The issue is I needed to put single quotes around the 0 or 1 meaning this is the correct comparison operator.

```
if (samp=='0'){
```